# MySQL query to sort by one column and generate its ranking (equivalent to RANK OVER PARTITION oracle)

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a MySQL table like this:

```
id | points | rank | league_id
______________________________
1  | 84     | 0    | 1
2  | 55     | 0    | 1
3  | 104    | 0    | 1
4  | 123    | 0    | 2
```

What I want to accomplish is the following:

```
id | points | rank | league_id
______________________________
1  | 84     | 2    | 1
2  | 55     | 3    | 1
3  | 104    | 1    | 1
4  | 123    | 1    | 2
```

So - use the rank column to store ranks based on number of points, grouped by league_id. This may seem redundant but I need it for my purpose (it's for a fantasy sports website and having a rank column greatly simplifies a lot of PHP code and reduces the number of needed queries throughout the script).

I'm aware of the obvious solution - iterate through the rows, grouping by league_id and updating the ranks one by one. What I'm wondering is, is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed the title of your question, I think it answers a very common problem while switching from oracle to mysql and that it is worth pointing out. If you don't like it feel free to edit it

Comment: No problem, glad to help people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OTOH, so test first on a throw-away database, prepare to load backup:

```
  SET @rank = 1;
  SET @league = 0;

  UPDATE tablename
  SET 
      rank = @rank := IF(@league = league_id,@rank+1,1),
      league_id = @league := league_id
  ORDER BY league_id,points DESC;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY league_id,points DESC` -- so the biggest point will be `rank 1`.

Comment: @JW. you are of course correct, an oversight on my part, added it to the answer ;)

Comment: when I use this query with PDO, it raises error in this line : `rank = @rank := IF(@league = league_id,@rank+1,1),` for using := operator

Comment: @user3197818: not my stock-PDO, without any alterations. Are you 100% sure you are not using a naive library which tries to scan for parameters starting with `:=`? As in: you can reproduce it with straight PDO with nothing between? And also: you are sure you are using _mysql_?

Comment: no. I don't use anything extra, I just use mysql, php and PDO

Comment: Cannot reproduce that with `create table foo (bar int );insert into foo        values (1);` and `var_dump($pdo->query('SELECT bar = @rank := 1 FROM foo;')->fetchAll());`